# He was detected with brain tumour or he was detected with a brain tumour. Please correct the sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, articles, nouns, spoken-english

He was detected with brain tumour or he was detected with a brain tumour. Please correct the sentence. How to use the article and what’s the difference between two sentences?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumours are countable, so "*a* brain tumour" would be the correct way of saying it.

However, it is quite common for the names of medical diagnoses and procedures to be used in abbreviated form, so it is possible that some might use "brain tumour" as a noncountable diagnostic term in the way you stated. "Cancer" can also be a [countable noun](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cancer_1) - you could say "some cancers respond to treatment" - yet it is more common to use it as a noncountable noun, for example "he has cancer".

I would advise you include the article "a" as this is how most people would say it, but I wouldn't want to say that the other way is categorically incorrect in a medical context.

Comment: You've neglected that detected is also the wrong word in that structure, it should be diagnosed